# optimizing a function to find global and local peaks with R

Tags: optimization, r, global, local

Y 
I have 6 parameters for which I know maxi and mini values. I have a complex function that includes the 6 parameters and return a 7th value (say Y). I say complex because Y is not directly related to the 6 parameters; there are many embeded functions in between.

1. I would like to find the combination of the 6 parameters which returns the highest Y value. I  first tried to calculate Y for every combination by constructing an hypercube but I have not enough memory in my computer. So I am looking for kinds of markov chains which progress in the delimited parameter space, and are able to overpass local peaks.
2. when I give one combination of the 6 parameters, I would like to know the highest local Y value. I tried to write a code with an iterative chain like a markov's one, but I am not sure how to process when the chain reach an edge of the parameter space. Obviously, some algorythms should already exist for this.

Question: Does anybody know what are the best functions in R to do these two things? I read that optim() could be appropriate to find the global peak but I am not sure that it can deal with complex functions (I prefer asking before engaging in a long (for me) process of code writing). And fot he local peaks? optim() should not be able to do this

In advance, thank you for any lead

Julien from France

Comment: these kind of questions are better asked on http://www.crossvalidated.com

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Optimization and Mathematical Programming Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html) on CRAN.  I've personally found the differential evolution algorithm to be very fast and robust.  It's implemented in the DEoptim package.  The rgenoud package is another good candidate.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the [Metropolis-Hastings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis-Hastings_algorithm) algorithm. Since you are limiting each parameter to a range, the simple thing to do is let your proposal distribution simply be uniform over the range. That way, you won't run off the edges. It won't be fast, but if you let it run long enough, it will do a good job of sampling your space. The samples will congregate at each peak, and will spread out around them in a way that reflects the local curvature.